# Triggering MaxClockSkew when accessing WCF service

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0

I have a WCF service which has one end point with configuration of a MaxClockSkew set to 23:59:59 but with no security behavior, and another end point with the same configuration of MaxClockSkew and security configuration. The problem is when accessing the non secure endpoint no exception is thrown and when accessing the secure endpoint a security exception is thrown. I would like that both of the endpoints will throw exceptions, how can it be done?

Thanks.

Aryeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security mode - security mode="Transport" - does not include time stamp in the message which cause the MaxClockSkew validation to ignore the message and not throws a security exception. Change the security mode to security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" which include time stamps and allow the MaxClockSkew validation to test the message for time delta.