# WCF & clock skew -- custom binding configuration ignored?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, binding

Our clients are facing the same clock skew problems that are haunting [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971785/how-to-fix-the-wcf-maxclockskew-problem-in-a-https-silverlight-application-contex) [many](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434109/why-doesnt-my-wcf-endpoint-throw-a-max-clock-skew-exception) people as well.

The answers in those pages and further web searching helped quite a bit, but I faced with a different problem.

When debugging on my local machine, I can see that the properties on the bindings are set correctly.
But as I can not test the code locally (I only have one clock), i have to publish the service to a test server. Yet when I connect to the service with a skewed clock, I still receive `MessageSecurityException`s.

My first thought was that the binding gets modified after creation, but both I and a coworker on this project confirmed that the bindings are created once and not touched after.

I am obviously Doing It Wrong [TM]. I would be very grateful if someone could shed light on the matter. Thank you in advance.

---

This is the code that creates the binding:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;

// ... blah blah ...

// fix ongoing security
sbe.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
sbe.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
sbe.LocalClientSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

sbe.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
sbe.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
sbe.LocalServiceSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

// fix bootstrap security
SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters sct = null;

if (sbe is SymmetricSecurityBindingElement)
{
    SecurityTokenParameters tokenParameters = 
((SymmetricSecurityBindingElement)sbe).ProtectionTokenParameters;
    if (tokenParameters is SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)
    {
        sct = tokenParameters as SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters; 
    }
}
else if (sbe is TransportSecurityBindingElement)
{
    sct = sbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters
             .Endorsing
             .OfType<SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters>()
             .FirstOrDefault();
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Binding has neiter a " +
       "SymmetricSecurityBindingElement nor " + 
       "TransportSecurityBindingElement");
}

SecurityBindingElement bootbe = sct.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;

bootbe.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
bootbe.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
bootbe.LocalClientSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

bootbe.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
bootbe.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
bootbe.LocalServiceSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```

This is a call stack of the exception I receive in the service trace log:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ServerSecurityChannel`1.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationState)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityReplyChannel.ProcessReceivedRequest(RequestContext requestContext, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnInnerReceiveDone()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Dispatch()
System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.Invoke()
System.Runtime.ActionItem.CallbackHelper.InvokeWithoutContext(Object state)
System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: Is the setting applied on the service or on the client?

Comment: The bindings are created identically on both server and client; that's why the service sets the options on both the `LocalClientSettings` as well as the `LocalServiceSettings`

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I think I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should receive a `MessageSecurityException` if your message is rejected due to the times on the server and client differing by more than the clock skew setting.  Given your description I think what you're seeing is what is expected.

[According to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/435803/wcf-fails-to-differentiate-between-different-failure-conditions-and-just-throw-messagesecurityexception), the reason a `MessageSecurityException` is returned instead of something more specific is because

> Security exceptions can expose some very sensitive information and due
>   to this we decided not to expose any details from the security layer.
>   For example, the clock skew issue that you have mentioned, when
>   exposed in the fault exception, would provide an attacker the clock
>   skew settings of the service and gives information to craft a more
>   specific attack.