# WCF: Recognize clock skew error on server side

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I have a WCF client/service and I've been getting message security exceptions.  I know they're clock skew errors from testing/changing clock skew.  I get the default message security error on my client that doesn't tell me explicitly it's a clock skew, however I want to show a nice error message and I don't just want to assume all message security exceptions are clock skew.  So I was wondering if there's someplace on the server I could possibly detect clock skew and send back a better message, or if the security is checked before it hits my service code and I have no hope of detecting if it's clock skew or something else.

edit:
The message I get between 5 and 10 minutes is "... time is in future, skew is 5 min", however if I change my local time to be more than 10 minutes, it returns just a default message security exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think and hope that this question and answer with links will help you out!
[WCF & clock skew -- custom binding configuration ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423423/wcf-clock-skew-custom-binding-configuration-ignored)

Comment: Yea I saw that, so basically it's not possible because of security reasons?  It's weird to me because if the client/server has different skews (say, server has higher skew, 10 min, vs 5 min on client), I get a message on the client saying that the time is "in the future".  So I would assume I can get the same message on the server somehow and return my own custom message.